# Как регулярным выражением убрать все нецифровые символы

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть строка, состоящая из набора символов, например: `sdf547sd/<fs>>445asd5455sd`.

Как составить регулярное выражение, чтобы в строке оставить только цифры?

При использовании `[0-9]*` берется только первая группа цифр `547`.

Comment: А модификатор `g` указывали? Он как раз говорит находить не первое вхождение, а все. Сравните [без модификатора](https://regex101.com/r/lA2vH7/1) и [с модификатором](https://regex101.com/r/lA2vH7/2). Хотя здесь от языка еще зависит, если он сохраняет предыдущий поиск, то возможно в цикле можно найти все значения. Но зачем нам цикл, если есть модификатор? )

Comment: Еще один вариант - раз вам надо оставить только числа, то может быть стоит просто удалить "нечисла"? "Нечисла" можно обозначить как `[^0-9]` (в зависимости от диалекта можно использовать варианты `[^\d]` или `\D`) А "удалить" здесь значило бы - заменить пустым символом. Если бы вы привели пример того как удаляете и сказали что за язык используется, то ответы могли бы быть более точными.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Регулярное выражение само по себе описывает только *непрерывную последовательность символов*.

Если вы хотите оставить только одни цифры, вам нужно будет *удалить всё остальное*.

Это вы можете сделать заменив регулярное выражение *всё кроме цифр* на *пустое место*.

Например, с помощью **sed** это можно сделать так:

```
sed 's/[^0-9]//g'
```

С помощью **perl** аналогично:

```
s/[^0-9]+//g
```

(при этом замена происходит в переменной `$_`).

В **python** это выглядит так (один из вариантов):

```
re.sub( '[^0-9]+', '', line )
```

( замена происходит в переменной `line`, результат замены возвращается функцией ).

Как можно заметить во всех примерах регулярное выражение выглядит одинаково (или похоже). В действительности диалекты регулярных выражений различаются, но проявляется это только в более сложных случаях.

В данном случае:

- `/[^0-9]+/` -- что заменить (последовательность символов кроме цифр);
- `//` — на что заменить (на пустое место);
- `g` — модификатор, указывающий, что нужно выполнять *глобальную* замену, то есть заменять все вхождения регулярного выражения в строке, сколько раз бы они ни встречались.